# GroupSequence and order of evaluation in JSR 303

Tags: spring, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have a field of type `String` in a command bean which has to be validated in the following order.

- Must contain a value (not empty).
- Must have exactly 6 characters.
- Must confirm this regexp - `[0-9, a-f, A-F]+`

When any of them is violated, the rest must not be performed. I have tried to achieve this using `@GroupSequence` as follows.

```
@GroupSequence({TempBean.ValidationGroupNotEmpty.class, TempBean.ValidationGroupColourHexLength.class, TempBean.ValidationGroup.class, TempBean.class})
public final class TempBean
{
    @NotEmpty(groups={ValidationGroupNotEmpty.class}, message="Must enter a valid colour code.")
    @Length(min=6, max=6, groups={ValidationGroupColourHexLength.class}, message="Requires exactly 6 characters.")
    @Pattern(groups={ValidationGroup.class}, regexp="[0-9, a-f, A-F]+", message="Invalid colour code.")
    private String stringValue;

    public interface ValidationGroup{}
    public interface ValidationGroupNotEmpty{}
    public interface ValidationGroupColourHexLength{}

    // Getters and setters.
}
```

When the text-field is intentionally left blank, only `@NotEmpty` is performed but when I enter a value that violates the `@Length` and the `@Pattern` constraints, I'm getting both the messages as specified meaning they both are evaluated. This shouldn't happen. Only one of them should be performed at a time in the defined order. How can this be done?

I'm using Spring 3.2.0 and Hibernate Validator 4.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

You code looks fine and I even tested it against HV 4.3.1. It works as expected. You are evaluating the *Default* group right? Have you tried to debug?

Comment: Did you need to check conditionally in the Spring controller class like - only check for a specific group, when constraints with the other group(s) satisfy (i.e they return true)? I'm doing so which shouldn't be necessary at all. How did you code in the controller (or other action class which is mapped to a request)? Please let me know.

Comment: In addition to group sequence, when one of constraints fails, neither of them should be evaluated. Is this possible?

Comment: You could make use of Hibernate Validator's specific [fail fast mode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e3331) which stops validation after the first constraint violation ocurred.

Comment: @Gunnar : Could you please add that as an answer with a little example (maybe pseudo code)? I don't see in that reference.